# MS Chart Y Axis not staring from 0 Hours [RangeBar]

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, charts, mschart

I am using a rangebar mschart to plot some data. Y axis represents the time ( total of 24 hours). The chart is plotting data correctly, but **the y axis is not starting from 0 hours.** 
[image]

**Code**

```
 var IETable = (dt as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();
 chChart.DataBindCrossTable(IETable, "Number", "", "Start,Finish", "");

                  foreach (Series sr in chChart.Series)
                  {

                      sr.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
                      sr.YValueType = ChartValueType.Time;

                  }


                  chChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "h : tt";
                  chChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 2;
                  chChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
                  chChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IntervalOffset = 0;
                  chChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsMarksNextToAxis = true;
                  chChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = true;
```

I also tried AxisY.Minimum=0 and AxisY.Maximum=1. This starts Y axis from 0 but then plotting is not visible.

Comment: where is it starting from?

Comment: @Vajura Its starting from 8 pm (previous day). I have added a screenshot for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime minDate = new DateTime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime maxDate = minDate.AddHours(24);
chChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
chChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
```

Try this. You might need to change the **new DateTime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);** to fit the year and month etc when you will add stuff. Possible solution is to get **minDate** with **DateTime.Now** and substraction the hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: It was throwing an "ArgumentOutOfRange" Exception. "Year, Month and Day describe an un-representable datetime.But converting TextBox value to datetime did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Converting TextBox value to datetime did the trick.

```
DateTime minDate =Convert.ToDateTime(tbDate.Text);
DateTime maxDate = minDate.AddDays(1);
chChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate();
chChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate();
```